# How to pick ringtones and play it with alarms

Tags: android, ringtone

I am very new to android.

I am trying to set open a ringtone picker on clicking of a button (I could do this).

Now, I want to play the associated ringtone when each of them is clicked.

When the user pressed the OK button, I want the selected ringtone URI etc to be obtained and stored so that I can play that ringtone when the alarm starts.\

Please help me with the steps.

Regards,
Bhaskar